# Looking for code which will let me backup SQL Server 2005/2008/2008R2 database inside C# tests (MSTest)

Tags: c#, sql-server-2005, unit-testing, mstest, database-backups

I have found a starting point below, but I worry that I can miss calls to `CreateDbBackup()` and `RestoreDbBackup()`. I was hoping that I could write and use an attribute on my tests. Is this possible? How? I am using MSTest library and C# 4.0.

http://www.linglom.com/2008/01/12/how-to-backup-and-restore-database-on-microsoft-sql-server-2005/

```
internal void CreateDbBackup()  
{  
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myConStr"].ConnectionString))  
         {  
            SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();  
            cmd.CommandText = string.Format(@"BACKUP DATABASE [MyDatabase] TO  DISK = N'{0}' WITH  INIT ,  NOUNLOAD ,  NOSKIP ,  STATS = 10,  NOFORMAT", UtilityClassGeneral.DbBackupPath);  
            con.Open();  
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); 
        }  
    }  

    internal void RestoreDbFromBackup()  
    {  
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myConStr"].ConnectionString))  
        {  
            SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();  

            con.Open();  

            // Make sure to get exclusive access to DB to avoid any errors  
            cmd.CommandText = "USE MASTER ALTER DATABASE [MyDatabase] SET SINGLE_USER With ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE";  
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();  

            cmd.CommandText = string.Format(@"RESTORE DATABASE [MyDatabase] FROM  DISK = N'{0}' WITH  FILE = 1,  NOUNLOAD ,  STATS = 10,  RECOVERY ,  REPLACE", UtilityClassGeneral.DbBackupPath);  
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();  
        }  
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [SQL Server Management Objects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163409.aspx) (SMO). You should be able to use this to backup and restore SQL Server databases.

Comment: Thanks! How official / old / well tested is this?

Comment: Microsoft developed this starting with SQL Server 2005. It can be installed during the SQL Server installation.